# Installing LAMP stack without MySQL on AWS

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, aws

I want to host basic websites on AWS. I got my head around creating an instance, choosing a distro (Ubuntu) and installing Apache. I want to install PHP, but these basic websites don't require a database.

The LAMP tutorials give the following command for installing PHP, but I'm uncertain if you want this command for a server not running MYSQL.

`sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`

These websites are intended for small-to-medium enterprises and only need PHP for a basic contact form script.

Would it be as easy as just using the following command?

`sudo apt-get install php`

Comment: You will not need `php-mysql` if there is no database installed. Depending on how basic these sites are, you may need some other PHP packages, though, so be ready to read your Apache error log to determine which libraries are missing as you try to load the sites and see errors 

Comment: LAMP always includes mysql; want you want is LAP ;-)  `sudo apt-get install php` no to connect apache you need `libapache2-mod-php` for securing your site you need `php-mcrypt`.  Generally I would suggest to install the default an instabce offers so with nysql even if you do not use it,  Your base install should be as close to an original instance as possible (every change you make you need to docunent and maintain so the less you change the better ;) )